# Pythagoras' Golfing Grid

Tags: code-golf, math

Recently, I created a [binary word search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/a-pretty-binary-grid) that got me working with grids. It was fun, so I wanted to create some more similar content. Meet Pythagoras' Golfing grid:

[image: Screenshot of the grid.]

Each of `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k` and `T` represent a numeric value.

Now consider an orthogonal triangle along the lower diagonal of this grid (so the vertical side is `d`, `g`, `i`; the horizontal base is `i`, `j`, `k` and; the hypotenuse is `d`, `T`, `k`).

We'll then assign some value constraints to various different cells/sums of cells, in a manner similar to Pythagoras' theorem:

- Let \$a = d + g + i\$
- Let \$b = i + j + k\$
- Let \$c = f = dk\$
- Let \$T = f - eh\$

You'll be given the value of \$T\$. You should then output the values of \$d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k\$, in that order, such that \$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\$ (equivalently, such that \$(d+g+i)^2 + (i+j+k)^2 = f^2 = (dk)^2\$) and such that \$T = f - eh\$

For example, given a value \$T = 55\$, the output should be:

> `4,5,80,22,5,22,22,20`

as \$T = f-eh = 80-5\times5\$ and

$$\begin{align}
(4+22+22)^2 + (22+22+20)^2 & = 48^2 + 64^2 \\
& = 2304 + 4096 = 6400 \\
& = 80^2 = (4\times20)^2
\end{align}$$

The resulting grid would look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the resulting populated grid.]

##### Input

For clarity, your input will be a numeric value \$T\$:

> 55

##### Output

For clarity, your output will be a comma delimited list of the values \$d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k\$:

> 4,5,80,22,5,22,22,20

##### Completion of Processing

There can be more than one answer for a given \$T\$, and as such, processing should complete upon discovery of the first valid set of values.

##### Loophole Prevention

Loopholes should not be utilized to achieve an answer. For example, returning hard coded values is prohibited.

##### Final Notes

While their is no official time limit, you can feel free to or not to add a variable cutoff time to your solution and return an answer of ***u*** (representing unsolvable) for the sake of brevity when reviewing answers. So long as this portion of your solution is clearly explained, it can be excluded from your size calculation.

If you *choose* to add a cutoff time, please make it an additional variable for input named *c*.

##### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Since it may not have been clear enough before: I think you should make it clearer that there is more than one valid solution (if there is a solution), and that the values in the grid are positive integers. Your wording on the output also seems unnecessarily strict - why not just say "output the values \$ d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k \$"?

Comment: Must the values be integers?

Comment: @att they're not required to be, no. You can force the input to be an integer, decimal, float, etc, so long as it accepts numeric input.

Comment: May some values be negative or zero?

Comment: @Arnauld so long as all constraints are met, the individual values can be *any* numeric value, to include [the most irrational number](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-irrational4).

Comment: Then it seems like we can just return \$(d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)=(1,1,5,0,5-t,2,-3,5)\$ (or similar hardcoded values) for any \$t\$. [Example code](https://tio.run/##LYw5bsJQFEV7VnGFBJ6uEYa4CfwgGlbwO0Rh4wEbxEfYShNlB0g0lGQfWQ8bYAnmGZDecO59Qxl9R9X6WBxqf2@StFmoplZfy4ABQw4Z@jVH9McMV01mjraGQjCBxhQfQ@me5@CnA8zFXyZESmRETmyIgiiJ7UpGC1s7E1mLhBN4yCWL1ojFKESUktvWWD833Lcw@8rs0sHO5HZXq16CXiXRJTQxp7xzXYzkNH6BUnL/pH4f2UsK6ZYy@Ejl8QYzWPf/8@16kWrhE9bt72Q5nd/mAQ).

Comment: @Arnauld great loophole, edited my challenge to prevent loopholes.

Comment: I think this challenge should be moved to [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/58563) so that it can be specified more accurately. Preventing hard-coded values is basically a [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11197/58563). Besides, with the current spec, we can just choose random values for \$a\$ and \$b\$ and still directly compute a matrix from them.

Comment: It [*was*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23875/95204) in the Sandbox

Comment: interesting idea ...... i started an attempt at answer at the link below but basically it seems like the results are not unique . i randomly generated pythagorean triples and back calculated everything else. e and h in particular seem to be completely random since all you have to do is pick two that when multiplied will add to make f-T. to avoid hard coding e or h then i just made e random? anyways. https://www.online-python.com/7Ioj30fsU4